# How to match objects with the same key-value pairs passed as arguments?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

### This is a FreeCodeCamp task named Wherefore art thou.

I have to Make a function that looks through an array of objects (first argument) and returns an array of all objects that have matching name and value pairs (second argument). Each name and value pair of the source object has to be present in the object from the collection if it is to be included in the returned array.

My solution passes all the checks besides this one: whatIsInAName([{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}], {"a": 1, "b": 9999, "c": 3}) should return []. And I wonder why the function returns the given array instead of an empty one. And if there is a way to make my function work eventually. My code is gonna be below. THANK YOU FOR HELP!

```
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
  let arr = [];
  const sourceKeys = Object.keys(source);

  for (let key in sourceKeys) {
    arr = collection.filter(
    obj => (Object.keys(obj).length >= sourceKeys.length) ?
    obj.hasOwnProperty(sourceKeys[key]) 
    && obj[sourceKeys[key]] === source[sourceKeys[key]] : 0);
  }

  return arr;
}
whatIsInAName([{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}], {"a": 1, "b": 9999, "c": 3});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a simple implementation using `Object.keys()` and `Array.every()`.

This means each returned item must include each key and value from the source, but *may* include extra keys and values:

```js
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
  return collection.filter(obj => Object.keys(source).every(key => obj[key] === source[key]));
}

console.log(whatIsInAName([{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}], {"a": 1, "b": 9999, "c": 3}));
console.log(whatIsInAName([{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}], {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}));
console.log(whatIsInAName([{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4 }], {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}));
console.log(whatIsInAName([{"a": 1, "c": 3, "d": 4 }], {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! The solution looks like it was on the surface. The comment was really helpful either.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```js
function fltArr(collection, p) {
  const tst=Object.entries(p);
  return [...collection].filter(o=>
    tst.every(([k,v])=>o[k]==v)) // check for each key and value of p
}                                // that they are the same in o[k]

const arr=[{a: 1, b: 2, c:3, d:7},{a: 1, b: 2, d: 3}],
 patterns=[{a: 1, b: 9999, c: 3},{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3},{a: 1, b: 2, d: 3}];

patterns.forEach(p=>console.log(fltArr(arr,p)))
```

As far as I understand the question, the collection object *can* have extra properties (*not* specified in `p`) and still be a match. For this reason the first element is a match with the second test pattern.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Obviously, that worked for me. The problem was, I chose the wrong way to follow. But your solution will broaden my view on such kind of tasks. Now, it needs some time to think about though.